# iPhone X safe area not working

Tags: ios, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

Currently I’m working in this project where I need to resolve a UI issue for iPhone X. I did some reading that said developers can use safe areas in XIB and it will resolve the problem. So I did it, and the simulator looks fine, but not my real device.

[image]

All the UI Components are attached to safe area. But only iPhone X simulator looks okay. How do I resolve this?

Comment: In order to discover the discrepancy, I suggest you to enable the "Debug View Hierarchy" and check if there is anything strange, comparing simulator/device.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini there is nothing strange. just that the screen is not attached to the safe area. meanwhile UI from storyboard looks fine in real device and simulator. Just that UI from xib itself looks weird in real device.

Comment: I’d confirm that the binary on your phone matches the one in the simulator. Delete and reinstall, and clean too.

Comment: @brandonscript thanks alot mate. you were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer. Apparently, it was because XIB files were cached. I have to clean the project and re-run it. And it's working perfectly.

Comment: @Abdel did you assign the view to be attached with safe area? left, right, top and bottom?

Comment: For me either - I recreate constraints (after enabling save area). Clear and Build project and no luck.